# How to display results of a SQL query in Blazor Grid

Tags: sql, datagridview, datagrid, blazor

I'm looking to display the results from an arbitrary table in SQL in Blazor which *may* contain large data volumes. For example, my query might look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableX
```

Obviously this implies that the data model cannot be know at the compile time given this could be any table.

To get around not knowing that data structure ahead of time, I'm aware libraries, such as DevExpress, allow users to use DataTables - example [here](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t1105338/how-to-bind-a-blazor-dxgrid-to-a-datatable). However, this would be a problem as the number of results generated by a query grows.

Again, using DevExpress as an example, ["Large Data Source" components](https://docs.devexpress.com/Blazor/403737/grid/bind-to-data#large-data-server-mode-sources) are supported, however this requires one to know the data structure ahead of time.

In an ideal world, it would be interesting to know if there any "off the shelf" solutions that allow for pagination/virtualization of results without needing to know the underlying data structures ahead of time.

Any help/pointers to documentation would be appreciated!

Comment: I think that would be a very generic solution, but let's see what others think.

Comment: You can use IAsyncEnumerable to stream any large data in the runtime. If you can use of ORM such as EFCore you can also use generic method to implement a get query for any tables (entities) at the runtime.